# Views flashes for a moment when using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I have two parents inside my Layout file, say a rough skeleton

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout 
        id = id1
        visibility = viewModel.visibility1>
        .....
    </ConstraintLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout
        id = id2
        visibility = viewModel.visibility2>
        ....
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

And my view model is something like this

**ViewModel.java**

```
private boolean isActive;

public void setActive(boolean isActive){
    this.isActive = isActive;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.active);
}

@Bindable
public boolean isActive(){
    return isActive;
}

@Bindable("active")
public int getVisibility1(){
    return isActive ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}

@Bindable("active")
public int getVisibility2(){
    return isActive ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
}
```

Setting the view model in `OnCreateView` in fragment.

Now the issue is, when fragment loads, it shows both the containers for while before hiding one of them based on the condition. Any possible solutions to remove this flash without hardcoding the view visibility by code?

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Did you manage to solve it? I tried using `default=gone` but still I get flashes.

Comment: @Tanasis No we couldn't. Currently we have added some workarounds to handle it because all are proper approach failed.

Comment: I see thanks! I did some research my self, and (at least in my case) it seems it related with the way we create the fragment.